# Java library to load CSV file into any JDBC database

Tags: library, java, csv, jdbc

I would like to know if there is any library that I can use to populate tables in my application (tests and data migration) from CSV files using JDBC. I know some databases has this feature but I would like a database neutral solution. I also found this post [Java: How to Load CSV file into Database](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-load-csv-file-to-database/) but I would like to use a generic library for this task. Any suggestion?